# Xcode throwing errors when device is changed requiring re install of xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Im having issues with Xcode.  Every time I change my device for testing, or build for the simulator after using a device Xcode suddenly throws errors on all apps that were working just fine 2mins previously.

The errors to begin with are:

`Reference to 'kCGInterpolationNone' is ambiguous`  if this is fixed by say deleting the relevant section of code (even though this was fine a few mins ago) then other errors just replace it `cannot build module AVfoundation` and on and on...

Cleaning project does nothing to fix this, deleting derived `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`data does nothing either, including deleting the entire folder. Infact when deleting the derived data, it immediately re adds the module files and app files that I understood got added at build time, not immediately after deletion? The only way to fix is to delete and reinstall Xcode, then delete derived data and then restart Mac.  This issue is now happening on a daily basis and is becoming time consuming and annoying at best.

Comment: It would be worth you posting the compiler log for the build so we can see any errors. Others seem to mention cleaning out DerivedData followed by xcode restart before doing anything else.

Comment: Cleaning derived data and restart does nothing.  The problem wih posting complier log is the errors are erroneous so would not be  helpful

Comment: Do you have #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> at the top of the file showing the ambiguous error.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is making sure Quartz.framework is in the project, but you probably have that already. Sorry can't come up with anything else.

Comment: Thanks anyway, its not a coding error/import error as it builds fine on xcode until i change device or run it on a simulator, then i have to re install xcode again.  It also affects other apps and previous versions of the app that have been on the appstore without issue